# How to get user claims inside ASP Core 2 method without Authorize attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have a method on an API that can be accessed anonymously.  I want to use resource authorization to determine if the user has access.  If the object is "public" than it can be accessed by anyone (including anonymous users).  If the object is "private" than it can only be viewed by logged in users.  This logic works fine if I have an authorize attribute on the method, but if not the User has no claims even when they are logged in.

Is there a way to get the user's claims in a method without an Authorize attribute?

Method looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("name/{name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
    {
        var activity = Repo.GetCommandLineActivity(name);
        if (activity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var isAuthed = await _authService.AuthorizeAsync(User, activity, new ViewIPublicPrivateRequirement());
        if (isAuthed.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok(activity);
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple, adding `[AllowAnonymous]` and `[Authorize]` did the trick.

Comment: I have change the attribute tag, but user's claim is still not available.. Running aspnet core 2.1

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to retrieve the `ClaimsPrincipal` even without the `[Authorize]` attribute, but it truly feels like a hack, and I wouldn't recommend it. If I were you, I'd create two different endpoints, one for public access, and the other for authenticated users.

That being said, the way to retrieve the `ClaimsPrincipal` is to call the `AuthenticateAsync` method. Note that this code is for ASP.NET Core 2.0, it would be slightly different for 1.1.

Here's the modified method:

```cs
[HttpGet("name/{name}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
{
    var activity = Repo.GetCommandLineActivity(name);
    if (activity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // based on the way your authentication is configured in services.AddAuthentication(),
    // this can be omitted (in which case, the default authenticate scheme will be used) 
    var authenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    var auth  = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(authenticationScheme);
    if (auth.Succeeded)
    {
        // CAUTION: HttpContext.User will STILL be null
        var user = auth.Principal;
        return Ok(activity);
    }

    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Caution: `HttpContext.User` will NOT be set if the `[Authorize]` attribute is omitted (or if `[AllowAnonymous]` is specified.

Comment: "HttpContext.User will NOT be set if the [Authorize] attribute is omitted (or if [AllowAnonymous] is specified." Are you sure about this? I got it working by setting [authorize] on top of my controller and using [allowanonymous] on my method.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you cannot.

If you check closely you will see that, when you have the `Authorize` attribute, the User object is of type `ClaimsPrincipal` and when you don't have it - it is of type `WindowsPrincipal`.

But you can always add custom `Authorize` attribute, or [Custom policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies), and check the user claims there and do your stuff.

Comment: I'm getting `ClaimsPrincipal` in both cases, but without the attribute it's properties are all null/empty.  Either way - how can I create a policy or Authorize attribute that gives me the user's claims while still allowing anonymous access?  Wouldn't both only work if the framework is adding the user's claims to the request?

Comment: Well this is the idea of the custom `Authorize` attribute - it is up to you to decide who is authorized, and who is not, based on your rules. You need to Inherit the default `Authorize` attribute, and then use yours on top of your classes/methods