# User.Identity.Name is empty with JWT when method is no decorated with Authorize in Asp.NET Core 3.0 API Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I have a Web Api project in .net core 3.1 and I have added JwT authentication.
The authentication and authorization work very well, but I need to get the UserId in every request. When the method is decorated with Authorize attribute, this works well.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name; //Get a value
        //Do something
    }
```

However I have some method which authentication is not required, but if an authenticated user make a request, I would like to get the userId, but in this case, user.Identity.Name is always null.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name; //null
        //Do somwthing
    }
```

My configuration in statur file is:

```
private void ConfigureJwt(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Add Auth scheme
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
        });

        AuthSettings authSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AuthSettings").Get<AuthSettings>();
        JwtIssuerOptions jwtIssuerOptions = Configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions").Get<JwtIssuerOptions>();

        services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidIssuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authSettings.SecretKey))
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    //When method is no decorated with Authorize, it not working
                    var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

        services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>(x =>
        {
            return new TokenService(Configuration);
        });
    }
```

TokenService class:

```
public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    IConfiguration configuration = null;
    AuthSettings authSettings = null;
    public TokenService(IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
        configuration = _configuration;
        authSettings = configuration.GetSection("AuthSettings").Get<AuthSettings>();
    }

    public string GenerateAccessToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, ref JwtIssuerOptions jwtIssuerOptions)
    {
        //var authSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(AuthSettings));
        //var authSettings = configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings").Get<AuthSettings>();
        jwtIssuerOptions = configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions").Get<JwtIssuerOptions>();

        var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authSettings.SecretKey));
        var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken (
            issuer: jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,
            audience: jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,
            claims: claims,
            expires: jwtIssuerOptions.Expiration,
            //expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
            signingCredentials: signinCredentials
        );

        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
        return tokenString;
    }

    public string GenerateRefreshToken()
    {
        var randomNumber = new byte[32];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }
    }
    public ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(string token)
    {
        TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = GetValidationParameters();

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        SecurityToken securityToken;
        var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);
        var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
        if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");

        return principal;
    }

    private TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters()
    {
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false, //you might want to validate the audience and issuer depending on your use case
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authSettings.SecretKey)),
            ValidateLifetime = false //here we are saying that we don't care about the token's expiration date
        };
        return tokenValidationParameters;
    }
}
```

AuthController

```
    [HttpPost, Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        if (loginModel == null)
            return BadRequest("Invalid client request");

        var sessionInfo = await userBo.LoginUser(loginModel);
        if (sessionInfo == null)
            return Unauthorized();

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, sessionInfo.User.BusinessEntityId.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, sessionInfo.User.RoleCode)
        };

        JwtIssuerOptions tokeOptions = null;
        var accessToken = tokenService.GenerateAccessToken(claims, ref tokeOptions);
        var refreshToken = tokenService.GenerateRefreshToken();

        await tokenBo.SaveToken(
            new Token()
            {
                BusinessEntityId = sessionInfo.Person.BusinessEntityId,
                RefreshToken = refreshToken,
                RefreshTokenExpiryTime = tokeOptions.Expiration
            }
        );

        sessionInfo.TokenInfo = new TokenInfo()
        {
            AccessToken = accessToken,
            RefreshToken = refreshToken
        };
        return Ok(sessionInfo);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453591/how-to-get-user-claims-inside-asp-core-2-method-without-authorize-attribute

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if the controller doesn't need authorize, it will not add the user information into pipeline claims, so the user name is always null.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to add a custom middleware to check if the request contains the Authorization header. If it contains you could get the username and add it into http context item.

Then you could directly get the username in the api controller instead of getting it from User.Identity.Name.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Add below middleware into startup.cs Configure method:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // you could get from token or get from session. 
            string token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                var tok = token.Replace("Bearer ", "");
                var jwttoken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(tok);

                 var jti = jwttoken.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
                context.Items.Add("Username", jti);
            }
    
            await next();

        });
```

Controller get the username:

```
        object value;
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("Username", out value);

        var username = value.ToString();
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After changing an application from using cookie-based authentication to using JWT I ran into this problem. You can work around it — sort of — by creating an [authorization handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorization-handlers) with no requirements thus allowing anonymous users access. The ASP.﻿NET pipeline doesn't know which requirements will be required so it will provide the credentials of the user if they are present in the request. The end result is that anonymous users are allowed but if credentials are provided they will be available.

The trivial requirement:

```cs
class RequireNothing : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

And the handler:

```cs
class RequireNothingHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RequireNothing>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RequireNothing requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

If the request contains credentials they will become available in the `User` object but the requirement also allow anonymous users access.

To use the requirement you can create a policy (and also add the handler to the DI container):

```cs
services
    .AddAuthorization(options => options
        .AddPolicy("AlsoAllowAnonymous", policy => policy
            .AddRequirements(new RequireNothing())))
    .AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RequireNothingHandler>();
```

To combine authenticated and anonymous access you decorate the action or controller with the attribute:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "AlsoAllowAnonymous")]
```

Unfortunately, this might not work so well. If you are using a long-lived JWT refresh tokens and short-lived access tokens that are refreshed when a 401 challenge is received there will be no challenge after the access token expires and the user will access the end-point anonymously possibly resulting in a degraded user experience even though the user has authenticated and has a refresh token to prove that.

This problem is not unique to using an authorization handler and you get more control by providing two different end-points: one for anonymous users and another one for authenticated users. You need some extra logic on the client side to select the correct API for things to work out right though.